# anam/phantommagick - Binary does not exist in server Oracle Linux Server 7.6

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, phantomjs, anamorphism

I am working laravel project, I convert the view page as an image using anam/phantommagick package [enter link description here](https://github.com/anam-hossain/phantommagick#binary). It Working fine in my local system (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS).But move the server it's not working.

i got below error
[image]

I added the **phantomjs-linux-x86-binary** Dependencies .

Comment: Have you checked the path to the binary?

Comment: @Dan
Yes, I tried below code too 

$conv = new Converter();
$conv->setBinary("BASE_PATH/vendor/anam/phantomjs-linux-x86-binary/bin/phantomjs");
  
      $conv->make('https:facebook.com') 
       ->toPng() 
       ->save(public_path().'/multipage1.png');